# Cambiar URL sin recargar la página

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, url

Sé que es una pregunta muy general, pero tengo esta duda. La cuestión es que he visto que muchos grandes sitios lo hacen. Os dejo dos ejemplos: https://elpais.com/elpais/2018/09/10/album/1536577621_182478.html
https://www.muyinteresante.es/curiosidades-motor/fotos/hyundai-santa-fe-el-protector

Como podéis ver, conforme uno hace scroll hacia abajo y va viendo las diferentes imágenes de la galería, la URL cambia.

Creo que esto se hace porque así aumenta el número de páginas visitadas y facturan más dinero, ¿estoy en lo cierto? Si es así, me gustaría hacer lo mismo en mi sitio web (y sino también por curiosidad), pero no sé por dónde empezar (parece que no funciona con los típicos anchors).

¿Alguien puede iluminarme?

Gracias a todos!

Comment: Por lo que veo en el primer ejemplo, sí parece tratarse de anchors o, al menos, lo que cambia de la url es la parte que viene detrás de la almohadilla. El segundo caso sí que cambia la url, añadiendo un /id que puedes lograr, por ejemplo, con un replaceState o pushState, dependiendo de si quieres que puedan navegar por todos los cambios de url al darle al botón de volver atrás

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, Javi. En el primer ejemplo cambia la parte de la almohadilla pero si inspeccionas el código no hay anchors, sino bloques que tienen un ID. Me gustaría lograr algo como el segundo ejemplo. ¿Podrías dar algún detalle sobre 'replaceState' y 'pushState' o pasarme alguna documentación que esté bien para su implementación? ¡Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: Esta página creo que lo explica: http://blog.alebanzas.com.ar/2011/11/html5-pushstate-no-mas-location-hash/

Comment: @dACEvid el beneficio no va por el lado económico, va por el lado de que si vos copias esa url, y la compartis, la persona que ingrese a la página, va a ser apuntada a la sección de la página que la persona compartió